# Guzzle HTTP / Curl error 7 for Laravel app running with Supervisord on localhost Mac OS

Tags: php, laravel, curl, macos-catalina, supervisord

Laravel app works fine if It's started manually with the command "php artisan octane:start".

So I decided to run with supervisor and I discovered that all external HTTP requests were rejected with curl error 7. Below is a test configuration with curl

------ curl-test.conf -------

```
[program:curl_test]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=/bin/sh -c "curl -v google.com"
autostart=true
loglevel=debug
autorestart=false
stdout_logfile=/tmp/curl-test.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

------------------ curl-test.log -----------

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 216.58.223.206...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 216.58.223.206: Software caused connection abort
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 216.58.223.206...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 216.58.223.206: Software caused connection abort
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened as a result of an internet firewall restriction on my mac. This issue is closed now

Comment: I suggest you to accept your answer (yes you can accept your own answer)